# Serve static files in symfony2

Tags: symfony

I really don't know how asset function works:
where should I put the static files such as js and css and images and how asset function can determinate their location ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In twig, the `{{ asset() }}` function search in your web directory. If you want to access to a file which is in `web/images/mypic.jpg`, use `src="{{ asset('images/mypic.jpg')}}"`.

For **JS** and **CSS**, you can use the `Resources/public` directory of your bundle and use the `stylesheet` and `javascript` tag in your view
see =>

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html#including-javascript-files

Comment: Thanks a lot ! that what I was looking for , Asset looks in the Web directory!